# Retina-ready images look blurry on "normal" displays

Tags: email, content-builder

When building templates and emails, any high-rez graphic asset with sharp details in it looks significantly blurry in Outlook, Gmail, etc. I had two different people, on very different systems (Mac, PC) notice and complain. I absolutely see the problem in Content Builder on my system.

The original assets were x3.05 rez, I also tried an exact x2 resolution. (That is, the asset is configured to display as 556px wide and the asset is 1112px.)

Everything I found talks about 'normal' assets looking blurry on Retina displays due to upscaling - this problem is the **other** way around.. I assume it's because most email/web clients use mediocre bilinear scaling.

How come this is a problem in my universe, but not for the rest of the internet?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Content Builder, but generically speaking, you use a srcset and specify multiple images, demonstrated in such articles as [this one](http://thenewcode.com/944/Responsive-Images-For-Retina-Using-srcset-and-the-x-Designator).

Comment: This is great! srcset could definitely be a solution for this.